# Dynamic setting of Log4j level across multiple JVMs

Tags: java, log4j, jmx

I am working in an application has a number of plain vanilla Java components, each of which runs in a separate JVM. All these components use Log4j and there is no option to change to another logging library.

As the title implies, I am looking for an "easy" way to **dynamically apply a Log4j logging level across all components/JVMs**. By "easy", I mean without rewriting the source code (otherwise, one can use, for instance, an interface to get/set the logging level, and have all classes implement that interface).

There are articles on the web about using JMX (for instance, via the LoggerDynamicBean class (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jmx/LoggerDynamicMBean.html) of the Log4j distribution.

An interesting such article describes how to implement this using an application server (Tomcat): http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/32359/1954. The application server seems necessary as an implementation of the MBeanServer class, to which all the loggers will be registered by Log4j as MBeans.

**Is there any implementation that does this dynamic logging level setting, across multiple JVMs, either via JMX, or via any other means?**

Comment: Across JVMs? No, you'd need to talk to each JVM, because they'll each have their own loggers, JMX listeners, etc.

Comment: Or talk to the same component. For example if they all can talk to a db or filesystem store the logging level there.

Comment: Yes, these are thoughts that I have made, too. I was just hoping that I am missing something more "automated". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple.  Point all the JVMs to the same log4j configuration file use this to have them reload occasionally.

`PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch( yourConfigFile, yourReloadInterval);`

Comment: This is a "Plan B' I have been considering, but the trouble is, constantly reloading the configuration file has potential concurrency issues (or so it appears in some test that I have done).